# Cycle through agenda files list not working

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am using emacs with org-mode on OSX. Since I have a lot of .org files added to my agenda and it would be good for clean-up purpose if I could cycle through them and maybe also remove them if not needed.

For this, I tried using org-cycle-agenda-files

It only goes to the file that is at the top of the agenda list and does not cycle through remaining files.

Is there some configuration change that I can do to fix it?

On evaluation of expression

```
(org-agenda-files t)
```

I can see the list of my agenda files

```
("~/work/pubsub/onCall/File4OnCall.org" "~/work/pubsub/tasks/DocumentExistingAlarms/DocumentExistingAlarms.org" "~/work/pubsub/tasks/1739_alarmCBOpen/TaskAnalysis.org" 
"~/work/docs/workNotes/OfficsTasks.org" "~/work/docs/workNotes/GeneralTodos.org" "~/work/pubsub/documents/notes/general/CodeLooks.org" "~/work/pubsub/documents/notes/general/Tasks2Do.org" ...)
```

Comment: If you prefer this forum over the other one, then delete the other thread so that we are not spinning our wheels in two locations.

Comment: Sure, here keeping your latest comment

Comment: By @lawlist :  
In that case, the only real thing you can do is copy the entire source code for org-cycle-agenda-files to your scratch buffer and starting putting in some messages with values to see why it is not working. You should be using at least the version of org-mode that comes with Emacs 25.1, but I suppose you can debug an older version if you really want to

Comment: `org-cycle-agenda-files` (`C-,`) is working for me (org 9.0.3.)

Comment: For Debian Stretch users experiencing this bug, see [#870459](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870459).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `org-cycle-agenda-files` is broken in `org-mode` version 8.2.10 (which ships with Emacs 25.1).  Here is a working function:

```lisp
(when (version= org-version "8.2.10")
  (defun org-cycle-agenda-files ()
    "Cycle through the files in `org-agenda-files'.
If the current buffer visits an agenda file, find the next one in the list.
If the current buffer does not, find the first agenda file."
    (interactive)
    (let* ((fs (org-agenda-files t))
           (files (append fs (list (car fs))))
           (tcf (if buffer-file-name (file-truename buffer-file-name)))
           file)
      (unless files (user-error "No agenda files"))
      (catch 'exit
        (while (setq file (pop files))
          (if (equal (file-truename file) tcf)
              (when (car files)
                (find-file (car files))
                (throw 'exit t))))
        (find-file (car fs)))
      (if (buffer-base-buffer) (org-pop-to-buffer-same-window (buffer-base-buffer))))))
```